# Open Street Map Styled Maps Wizard Like Google Map

Tags: styles, openstreetmap

I am trying to get the Styled Maps Wizard for the OSM, but I can't find it at all.
I need the Styled Maps Wizard for OSM just like Google map have.
Please go to the following link for the google map have this option.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter

Now the use of the above link is that you can change the style of the map and get JSON and static map from the above link.

So I need the same things for the **Open Street Map**, hence is there is any way provided by the OSM service just like Google does.
Please let me know if there is any way, so that I can use it, I have tried a lot but still no luck at all.

Comment: Why do you think there is a styled maps wizard for OSM?

Comment: http://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Styles

Comment: Because in google map there is an option for Feature type,Element type,Color, etc... And you can select these feature the same time. Also you can get styled Map as you want and get the code either in JSON or Static Map. So I just looking that for OSM, because I want to use the same for the OSM.

Comment: You might find that [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) does what you want. It is not a "wizard", it's full software to create maps from OSM data.

Comment: Maybe OSM doesn't have one. Try Josm link though.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply, I'll try with TileMill and Josm.

Comment: I have tried with TileMill, but how can I export the project in HTML,CSS and javascript ?
Just Like Simple Map of Mapbox
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/